# Why does this pattern occur with derivatives?

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x) = \dfrac{x^5}{20}$.

The first derivative of $f(x)$ is $\dfrac{x^4}{4}$. If we equal these two functions, the solution for $x$ is $\{0, 5\}$.

$$\dfrac{x^5}{20} = \dfrac{x^4}{4}$$

The second derivative of $f(x)$ is $x^3$. If we equal the first and the second derivative of $f(x)$, the solution for $x$ is $\{0, 4\}$.

$$\dfrac{x^4}{4} = x^3$$

Doing this process with the second and the third derivative ($3x^2$), the solution will be $\{0, 3\}$.

$$x^3 = 3x^2$$

Equaling the third and the fourth derivative ($6x$), the solution will be  $\{0, 2\}$.

$$3x^2 = 6x$$

The solution of the process between the fourth and the fifth derivative ($6$) is $1$.

$$6x = 6$$

Why this pattern occurs?

Comment: What exactly is your question

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac{d}{dx}[x^n]=nx^{n-1}$

If we were to want to find the solutions to $x^n = \frac{d}{dx}[x^n]$, i.e. find the solutions to $x^n=nx^{n-1}$, we can subtract to one side and factor, using introductory algebraic techniques.

We get:

$$x^n - nx^{n-1}=0$$

simplifying to:

$$x^{n-1}(x-n)=0$$

The above has solutions $0$ and $n$.

The pattern you describe is simply a result of this.